# Count or monitor files sent from my PC

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, kali-linux

Is there a way I can count or know the number of files sent from my PC? Either copied or cut from an internal hard drive?

Comment: Such files are normally copied by networking. I do this with Sync Back Pro and it can tell me how many files moved. That is one way.

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer.. so, are you just talking about stuff done through the windows explorer? .. Any program can transfer any file it wants and there is no way to know it other than the fact that you have allowed it internet access.. on whichever port and IP it is allowed to talk to.  If you are talking about inside of a LAN and explorer only.. then maybe.. partially.. I would need to look at what hooks are avail.  I think the ultimate answer to you would be no, you can't really do this without your own network layer.. maybe I am wrong

Comment: It depends.  Are you asking in general?  Or do you have specific method?  Providing a lot more detail will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the software or protocol used to move or transfer the files. If the software or protocol writes logs or supports reporting, or has hooks allowing 3rd parties to do this, then yes. Not knowing specifically the protocols or programs doing this, or not being able to control the programs and protocols, which is perhaps more complex, we cannot give a better answer than that.